# How do I reduce the build size?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, build, size

I am facing an issue while deploying my React frontend site. The total size of my build is 348.39 MB, following is my build script:

"build": "npm install --omit=dev && react-scripts build && rm -rf ./node_modules && rm -f ./package-lock.json && ls -la",

as you can see I have added command to delete the node_modules. Following the output of ls -la to verify the file that are being zipped

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjuMJ.png)

but cyclic's bundle inspector is showing this...

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR7zB.png)

I deleted the node modules but somehow they are still there (refer to the 2nd image)